# Insert rsh and module load in perl script

Tags: perl, bash

I am writing a perl script to start vnc session.

Firsr I need to rsh to a server then load a module, next execute the "vncserver -otp".

```
my $mod=`module load turbovnc-1.0.0; vncserver -otp 2> tmp_vnc.log`;

my $launch=`rsh $host /"$mod/"`;

print $launch;
```

But it does not work, any suggestions??

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you need to use rsh?  Can you use ssh to avoid the security holes?  Also, what is the error message?  What is in $host and $mod?  Check by printing them.

Comment: Thank you for response. I need to use rsh since it does not need authentication. $host is the server's name which sets the vnc server, and $mod is two bash commands.

Comment: If you can rsh into the server and run commands without authentication that's a security hole.  I would suggest setting up ssh keys to automatically handle authentication and to shut down rsh.  http://oreilly.com/pub/h/66  Also, $mod is not two bash commands.  As written, $mod is the output of two bash commands.  Print $mod to see.

Comment: Thank you for help. I modify $launch as `rsh $host "module load turbovnc-1.0.0; vncserver -otp 2> tmp_vnc.log"`, it can work, but not my expected work. In tmp_vnc.log, it cannot start vncserver. But in command line, first I input "module load turbovnc-1.0.0" then "vncserver -otp > tm-_vnc.log", it can work. Why does that script not work?

Comment: It illustrates "module load turbovnc-1.0.0" this command does not work...

Comment: If you ssh into the remote server normally and run `module load turbovnc-1.0.0` then `vncserver -otp 2> tmp_vnc.log` as two separate shell commands, does it do what you want it to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean to use backticks in your first line?

```
my $mod=`module load turbovnc-1.0.0; vncserver -otp 2> tmp_vnc.log`;
```

This sets `$mod` to be the *output* of this sequence of commands, like running

```
(module load turbovnc-1.0.0; vncserver -otp 2> tmp_vnc.log) | rsh $host
```

from the shell. You probably wanted to say

```
my $mod='module load turbovnc-1.0.0; vncserver -otp 2> tmp_vnc.log';
```

which will set you up to run those specific commands on the remote host, and execute

```
rsh $host "module load turbovnc-1.0.0; vncserver -otp 2> tmp_vnc.log"
```

---

It also looks like in the `rsh` command that you are trying to escape the quotation marks with forward slashes. In Perl (and in everything else as far as I know), use a backslash to escape a special character.

```
my $launch=`rsh $host /"$mod/"`;    # / wrong /
my $launch=`rsh $host \"$mod\"`;    # \ right \
my $launch=`rsh $host "$mod"`;      # right, esc is not reqd in this case
```

Comment: Yeah, that is what I want to do.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I modify the backslash, but it still does't work. Do you know other methods? I don't know whether this method will work.

Answer (score 2):

A number of things could be going wrong, but probably the system commands are quietly failing.  Either loading the module, starting the vncserver or the rsh.  You can manually check for their success or failure by checking `$?` after each command... or you can use [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aSystem%3a%3aSimple) and it will error out if the command fails.

I would start by doing it as a series of shell commands to make sure it works.

Then I'd rewrite the code like so using IPC::System::Simple to do the error checking.  Also separating the $mod command into two commands, because I suspect you're getting back the output of running the vncserver, not loading the module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::System::Simple qw(run capture);

my $host = "something.something";

# Capture the output of loading the module
my $mod = capture('module', 'load', 'turbovnc-1.0.0');
warn "Module output: $mod\n";

# Run the VNC server
run('vncserver -otp 2> tmp_vnc.log');

# Connect to the host
my $launch = capture('ssh', $host, "/$mod/");
warn "ssh output: $launch";
```

There would seem to be a possibly false assumption that the location of the module on this machine is the same as the location of the module on the remote machine.  That or I don't understand what you're doing with `$mod`.